# Putting information in a html property to be accessible in a JS function

Tags: javascript, html

In the below code I have made up a property called 'foo' in the html button element. I want to be able to access that someway in the javascript function being called by 'onclick'

What I actually get if I try to call it in the same way as I would call the ID is 'undefined'

Or maybe there is some other way to send some data to the function that is not in the ID or value.

Here is a JS fiddle to demonstrate

https://jsfiddle.net/ftpeyrux/1/

```js
function assignAllClick(button) {
                            document.write('This is "foo": ' + button.foo + '<br>and this is "ID": ' + button.id);
                            }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="1" onclick="assignAllClick(this)" value="2" foo="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: *"In the below code I have made up a property called 'foo' in the html button element."* Um....where? The word "foo" doesn't appear anywhere in your questino other than in that sentence.

Comment: Also NEVER use document.write after the page has rendered. It will wipe the page. To add an attribute to your tag -  use `data-foo` and `button.getAtrribute("data-foo")`: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/j5kja57q/

Comment: You'll most likely want to read up on [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: I tried to edit this, but for clarity my question is can I embed data into a html element that can be accessed by a javascript function called by onload that is not in the ID or value section.

Comment: Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder apologies, I updated the fiddle with foo but not the snippet in the question so it was missing. I would never normally use document.write I just wrote that snippet to isolate the relevant code for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I actually get if I try to call it in the same way as I would call the ID is 'undefined'

Only official attributes have reflected properties. If you want to get an attribute that doesn't have a reflected property from an element, you use `getAttribute`:

```
console.log(button.getAttribute("foo")); // if the attribute is called foo
```

Live Example:

```js
function assignAllClick(button) {
  console.log('This is "data-foo": ' + button.getAttribute("data-foo"));
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="1" onclick="assignAllClick(this)" value="2" data-foo="I'm foo">Test</button>
```

---

Side note 1: If putting your own non-standard attributes on elements, always use the `data-` prefix. E.g., `data-foo`, not `foo`. (I've done that in the example above.) More [in the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Side note 2: You don't *call* properties, you access them (or read them or get their value, etc.). You call functions, methods, and constructors.